# Reversing an Array to Pick Values

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, excel-formula

I had a quick question- I am trying to pick up the closest filled cell starting from the right.

I tried doing it starting from the left but the problem lies when there is a blank cell it will not continue and stop before it. Can someone please help out?

Thanks

```
    Range("I6").Select
Selection.FormulaArray = "=INDEX(D6:H6,(MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK(D6:H6),0))-1)"
Range("I6").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Edit.

In essence. If I have 1 in D6, 2 in E6 and 3 in E6. I will end with w in I6, sine the code selects the -1th cell.

However, the problem is when I have

D | E | F | G | H | I |

1---2-------3-------2

It will be 2 in col I, row 6 since 2 comes before the blank (in E). 
If I start my array from the right side instead of the left- that will make things easier since I could look at the first filled cell.

Comment: Is there anything else to this code?  In trying to follow the goal of what is written, you are asking for cell I6 to match if a cell is blank in the range D6:H6 (will only show one value), then you copy I6 and paste the value to remove the formula.  You could forego the copy/paste by making the Range("I6").Formula=..., removing the quotations from the formula; you would need to add the worksheet application modifier as well.  Is this a valid assessment of the code and intent?

Comment: Thanks for the commnet Cryil. Please see above, i have clarified.

Comment: Ok, gave you a comment (made several edits to it as I tested it out)... i always mess using isblank (works in excel formulas) versus using isempty (works in VBA).   Hopefully that fits the bill, given your clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I am trying to pick up the closest filled cell starting from the right.*

Start at the far right and jump left

```
 cells(6,columns.count).end(xltoleft).select
```

selects the last filled cell in row 6 unless the row is completely empty when it selects A6

Comment: Could you please elaborate how I am supposed to use this?

Comment: I see whats happening- is there a way to fix the range of where the count starts? because there are filled cells on the right of I6 which isnt what I want

Comment: You can replace Columns.count with a specific number so if you wanted to find the first blank cell to the left of I6 you could use
      cells(6,9).End(xltoleft)   (since I is the 9th letter of the alphabet)
but it gets complicated. Using End mimics the use of Control and the cursor keys and its behaviour in the middle of a table is not intuitive

Answer (score 0):

In reading the update to the questions, I think you can do the following to tell you the value of the RC[-1] before the first blank:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 4 To 8 Step 1 'Calling out the Step in case you want to go from the right and say Step -1

If ISEMPTY(Cells(6, i)) Then

If ISEMPTY(Cells(6, 9)) Then

    Cells(6, 9).Value = Cells(6, i - 1).Value
    Else
    End If

Else
End If

Next i
End Sub
```

Let me know if that's what you're wanting.  This assumes that I6 is blank and I6 is filled in only if there was a blank, which allows you to skip to (in a roundabout way) terminate the loop.

Comment: Thank you! Found a simpler solution